# How can I keep a cellcontent static?

Tags: longtable, datetime

I have defined a TeX-macro to compare date and time information. Within a single box, there is no problem, but if used in a table, in different columns or lines, as shown below, the result is 0. Obviously, the boxes are unboxed and flushed. How may I save the information of box 1 (column/line) and box 2(column/line) to be processed in column 3 without typing them again?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
% \time
\newcount\hour  %
\newcount\hours %
\newcount\minutes %
\hour=\time \divide\hour by 60 
\minutes=\time
\hours=\hour \multiply\hours by 60 
\advance \minutes by -\hours
%end  \time
%begin  definitions of caldate
\newcount\fromcalyear %% 
\newcount\fromcalmonth %%
\newcount\fromcalday %%
\newcount\fromcalhour %%
\newcount\fromcalminutes %%
\newcount\tocalyear %% 
\newcount\tocalmonth %%
\newcount\tocalday %%
\newcount\tocalhour %%
\newcount\tocalminutes %%
\def\fromcaldate[#1-#2-#3 #4:#5]{%
\fromcalyear=#1 %
\fromcalmonth=#2 %
\fromcalday=#3 %
\fromcalhour=#4 %
\fromcalminutes=#5 %
\ \the\fromcalyear-\ifnum\fromcalmonth<10
0\fi\the\fromcalmonth-\ifnum\fromcalday<10
0\fi\the\fromcalday\ \ifnum\fromcalhour<10
0\fi\the\fromcalhour:\ifnum\fromcalminutes<10 0\fi\the\fromcalminutes
\vskip0.1\baselineskip}% 
\def\tocaldate[#1-#2-#3 #4:#5]{%
\tocalyear=#1 %
\tocalmonth=#2 %
\tocalday=#3 %
\tocalhour=#4 %
\tocalminutes=#5\ % 
\the\tocalyear-\ifnum\tocalmonth<10
0\fi\the\tocalmonth-\ifnum\tocalday<10
0\fi\the\tocalday\ \ifnum\tocalhour<10
0\fi\the\tocalhour:\ifnum\tocalminutes<10 0\fi\the\tocalminutes
\advance\fromcalyear by -\tocalyear\multiply\fromcalyear by
-1  %
\advance\fromcalmonth by -\tocalmonth\multiply \fromcalmonth
by-1  %
\advance\fromcalday by -\tocalday \multiply \fromcalday by-1  %
\advance\fromcalhour by -\tocalhour \multiply \fromcalhour by-1  %
\advance\fromcalminutes by -\tocalminutes \multiply \fromcalminutes by-1  %
\vskip0.1\baselineskip}% 
\def\rescaldatetime{(\the\fromcalyear)-(\the\fromcalmonth)-(\the\fromcalday) (\the\fromcalhour):(\the\fromcalminutes)}
\def\rescaldate{(\the\fromcalyear)-(\the\fromcalmonth)-(\the\fromcalday)}
\def\rescaltime{(\the\fromcalhour):(\the\fromcalminutes)}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}}
\fromcaldate[2013-01-01 13:00]
\tocaldate[2014-02-04 14:11]
\rescaldatetime\\
\\
\fromcaldate[2013-01-01 13:00]&
\tocaldate[2014-02-04 14:11]&
\rescaldatetime\\
&&
\rescaldatetime\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Table cells form groups, so non global assigments in them get forgotten as soon as the group ends.

Comment: I'm not sure what the `\rescaldatetime` macro is supposed to output with `\fromcaldate[2013-02-01 14:00]` and `\tocaldate[2014-01-04 13:11]`: I get `(1)-(-1)-(3) (-1):(11)` that doesn't make much sense.

Comment: (1)-(-1)-(3) (-1):(11) means: plus 1 year minus 1 month plus 3 days minus 1 hour plus 11 minutes minus sign - conflicts with separator sign -, therefore I used ()

Comment: So you are reinventing roman numerals in calendar context?

Comment: @percusse: No I'm not.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not that clear what the code is doing but the fact that the values are not available is not really related to the table other than table cells form a group: you would see the same if you surrounded the settings with `{...}` the values would revert at the group end.

This just makes all your definitions global so they are available outside the group:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
% \time
\newcount\hour  %
\newcount\hours %
\newcount\minutes %
\hour=\time \divide\hour by 60 
\minutes=\time
\hours=\hour \multiply\hours by 60 
\advance \minutes by -\hours
%end  \time
%begin  definitions of caldate
\newcount\fromcalyear %% 
\newcount\fromcalmonth %%
\newcount\fromcalday %%
\newcount\fromcalhour %%
\newcount\fromcalminutes %%
\newcount\tocalyear %% 
\newcount\tocalmonth %%
\newcount\tocalday %%
\newcount\tocalhour %%
\newcount\tocalminutes %%
\def\fromcaldate[#1-#2-#3 #4:#5]{%
\global\fromcalyear=#1 %
\global\fromcalmonth=#2 %
\global\fromcalday=#3 %
\global\fromcalhour=#4 %
\global\fromcalminutes=#5 %
\ \the\fromcalyear-\ifnum\fromcalmonth<10
0\fi\the\fromcalmonth-\ifnum\fromcalday<10
0\fi\the\fromcalday\ \ifnum\fromcalhour<10
0\fi\the\fromcalhour:\ifnum\fromcalminutes<10 0\fi\the\fromcalminutes
\vskip0.1\baselineskip}% 
\def\tocaldate[#1-#2-#3 #4:#5]{%
\global\tocalyear=#1 %
\global\tocalmonth=#2 %
\global\tocalday=#3 %
\global\tocalhour=#4 %
\global\tocalminutes=#5\ % 
\the\tocalyear-\ifnum\tocalmonth<10
0\fi\the\tocalmonth-\ifnum\tocalday<10
0\fi\the\tocalday\ \ifnum\tocalhour<10
0\fi\the\tocalhour:\ifnum\tocalminutes<10 0\fi\the\tocalminutes
\global\advance\fromcalyear by -\tocalyear\multiply\fromcalyear by
-1  %
\advance\fromcalmonth by -\tocalmonth\multiply \fromcalmonth
by-1  %
\global\advance\fromcalday by -\tocalday \multiply \fromcalday by-1  %
\global\advance\fromcalhour by -\tocalhour \multiply \fromcalhour by-1  %
\global\advance\fromcalminutes by -\tocalminutes \multiply \fromcalminutes by-1  %
\vskip0.1\baselineskip}% 
\gdef\rescaldatetime{(\the\fromcalyear)-(\the\fromcalmonth)-(\the\fromcalday) (\the\fromcalhour):(\the\fromcalminutes)}
\gdef\rescaldate{(\the\fromcalyear)-(\the\fromcalmonth)-(\the\fromcalday)}
\gdef\rescaltime{(\the\fromcalhour):(\the\fromcalminutes)}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}}
\fromcaldate[2013-01-01 13:00]
\tocaldate[2014-02-04 14:11]
\rescaldatetime\\
\\
\fromcaldate[2013-01-01 13:00]&
\tocaldate[2014-02-04 14:11]&
\rescaldatetime\\
&&
\rescaldatetime\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. But, am I right, that in tables boxes are flushed? If so, how may I prevent a single box from being flushed?

Comment: @M.Borck-Elsner I can not guess what you mean by flush in this context. The table box layout is unconnected to the evaluation of these macros.

Comment: Sorry, I used the wrong word. I meant the usage of the box and copy commands. Using box, the box is emptied, using copy, it is left untouched. But, I'm not that clear about my own question, give my some time...

Comment: @M.Borck-Elsner but the boxing is not relevant to the macros or arithmetic assignments they have all completed before the content is boxed and any values set are discarded at group end irrespective of whether a box is made.

Comment: Okay, I understand. For my own use, I defined a concept of tables built box by box, and I thought, it had a different handling of macros, but Im not sure, it needs more testing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way, the formatting of `\rescaldatetime` is left to the users, an example is given. Please consider the use of `\fromcaldate` and `\tocaldate` and `\rescaldatetime` carefully.

(This is TeX-Code!)

```
      %transformations of \time
\newcount\hour  %
\newcount\hours  %
\newcount\minutes  %
\hour=\time \divide\hour by 60 
\minutes=\time
\hours=\hour \multiply\hours by 60 
\advance \minutes by -\hours
%end transformations of \time
%begin  definitions of caldate
\newcount\fromcalyear %% 
\newcount\fromcalmonth %%
\newcount\fromcalday %%
\newcount\fromcalhour %%
\newcount\fromcalminutes %%
\newcount\tocalyear %% 
\newcount\tocalmonth %%
\newcount\tocalday %%
\newcount\tocalhour %%
\newcount\tocalminutes %%
\newcount\rescalyear %% 
\newcount\rescalmonth %%
\newcount\rescalday %%
\newcount\rescalhour %%
\newcount\rescalminutes %%
\def\fromcaldate[#1-#2-#3 #4:#5]{%
\global\fromcalyear=#1 %
\global\fromcalmonth=#2 %
\global\fromcalday=#3 %
\global\fromcalhour=#4 %
\global\fromcalminutes=#5 %
\ \the\fromcalyear-\ifnum\fromcalmonth<10
0\fi\the\fromcalmonth-\ifnum\fromcalday<10
0\fi\the\fromcalday\ \ifnum\fromcalhour<10
0\fi\the\fromcalhour:\ifnum\fromcalminutes<10 0\fi\the\fromcalminutes
\vskip0.1\baselineskip}% 
\def\tocaldate[#1-#2-#3 #4:#5]{%
\global\tocalyear=#1 %
\global\tocalmonth=#2 %
\global\tocalday=#3 %
\global\tocalhour=#4 %
\global\tocalminutes=#5\ % 
\the\tocalyear-\ifnum\tocalmonth<10
0\fi\the\tocalmonth-\ifnum\tocalday<10
0\fi\the\tocalday\ \ifnum\tocalhour<10
0\fi\the\tocalhour:\ifnum\tocalminutes<10 0\fi\the\tocalminutes}
\def\rescaldate{
\global\rescalyear=\the\fromcalyear %
\global\rescalmonth=\fromcalmonth %
\global\rescalday=\fromcalday %
\global\rescalhour=\fromcalhour %
\global\rescalminutes=\fromcalminutes %
\advance\rescalyear by -\tocalyear %
\global\advance\rescalmonth by -\tocalmonth  %
\global\advance\rescalday by -\tocalday   %
\global\advance\rescalhour by -\tocalhour   %
\global\advance\rescalminutes by -\tocalminutes   %
\vskip0.1\baselineskip}% 
\def\rescaldatetime{\rescaldate (\the\rescalyear)-(\the\rescalmonth)-(\the\rescalday)\ (\the\rescalhour):(\the\rescalminutes)}
%end definitions of caldate
Fromdate: \fromcaldate[2014-12-02 13:00]

Todate: \tocaldate[2012-11-05 04:16]

Resdate: \rescaldatetime


\def\rescaldatetime{{\bf Example} 
\rescaldate
 \ifnum\rescalyear>0 Years gone by \else Years to go \multiply\rescalyear by-1 \fi : (\the\rescalyear)

 \ifnum\rescalmonth>0 Months gone by \else Months to go \multiply\rescalmonth by-1\fi :
 (\the\rescalmonth)

 \ifnum\rescalday>0 Days gone by \else Days to go \multiply\rescalday by-1\fi :
 (\the\rescalday)

 \ifnum\rescalhour>0 Hours gone by \else Hours to go \multiply\rescalhour by-1\fi :
 (\the\rescalhour)

 \ifnum\rescalminutes>0 Minutes gone by \else Minutes to go \multiply\rescalminutes by-1\fi :
 (\the\rescalminutes)

}
\rescaldatetime
\bye
```